# array inputs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone tell me why in secondStage(frm) alert function is
not printing value of alert(frm.nColInRow1[0].value); "Coming here"
string is being printed

Here is the code

```
function firststage(frm) {

    alert(frm.nrows.value);

    for (i = 0; i < frm.nrows.value; i++) {
        var row = '<p id="rowNum' + i + '"> Enter number of columns in row ' + i + ':  <input type="text" name="nColInRow1[]" size="4"/></p>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    }

    if (i == (frm.nrows.value - 1)) {
        // Append a done button to move to next level   
        var button = '<input onclick="secondStage(this.form);" type="button" value="Add col">';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(button);
    }

}

function secondStage(frm) {
    alert("coming here");
    alert(frm.nColInRow1[0].value);
}
```

Comment: why not `$('<input type="button">').val("Add col").click(secondStage).appendTo($('#itemRows'));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the input elements name is `nColInRow1[]` not `nColInRow1`, use bracket notation since you have special characters in the key

```
function secondStage(frm) {
    alert(frm['nColInRow1[]'][0].value);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NAQN9/)

Comment: @user3073802 mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark at the top left cornot